# how to restrict a textbox to accept only two string i.e True/false (case insensitive) using regular expression in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to restrict a text box to accept only two strings i.e true/false using regular expression.

My code is working partially.  For lower case, it's working fine but I want it to be case insensitive.

my regular expression looks like this

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regAssign1" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="tb_Assign" ErrorMessage="Wrong Input!" forecolor="Red"
                    ValidationExpression="^(true)|(false)$" ValidationGroup="Submit"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

I want to get this done using a regular expression validator only. Suggestions using any other options like use JavaScript or use a drop-down list should be avoided.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a `<select>` or checkbox instead of having the user type it in?

Comment: Why don't you just use a dropdownlist with 2 values, or a checkbox, or a set of radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^(?i:true)|(?i:false)$
```

The `i` makes comparison case-insensitive for the words following the colon.

Alternatively, try this:

```
^([T|t][R|r][U|u][E|e])|([F|f][A|a][L|l][S|s][E|e])$
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is just like this...

```
^true$|^false$
```

This version allows whitespace before or after, which you can remove later with Trim.

```
^\s*true\s*$|^\s*false\s*$
```

I persistently tried to use ?i: for case insensitivity, it did not work in my RegularExpressionValidator. So here are some possible alternatives that will allow the three most likely case versions "true", "True", and "TRUE".

```
^true$|^false$|^True$|^False$|^TRUE$|^FALSE$
```

and allowing whitespace...

```
^\s*true\s*$|^\s*false\s*$|^\s*True\s*$|^\s*False\s*$|^\s*TRUE\s*$|^\s*FALSE\s*$
```

Also, as another answer pointed out, you will need a RequiredFieldValidator to disallow an empty TextBox.

Comment: This is still case sensitivr.

Comment: You are correct, however the Regex ^(?i:true)|(?i:false)$ will not work in an ASP.Net RegularExpressionValidator, I have tried it and get a javascript error "SyntaxError: invalid quantifier".

Answer (score 0):

You should change your regex to:

```
"^(true|false)$"
```

Please note that when using that, editor still accept empty string so you need to add a RequiredFieldValidator as well. Also for both of them if you added :

```
Display="Dynamic"
```

it would look better.